# Confirming ownership of a mobile app on facebook for developers

Tags: android, ios, flutter, facebook

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVSFL.png

Does someone know what needs to be done to be able to confirm ownership? I don't have this .txt file and I'm not sure what exactly it is and how to set it up.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the [learn more link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/release/mobile-app-verification)

First, you need to create an app-ads.txt file.
It could only contains one line.

```
facebook.com, [your facebook app id], RESELLER, c3e20eee3f780d68
```

Second, put the file to the root of your website domain which was set in google play console. (for example, https://example.com/app-ads.txt)
[image]

Finally, click the Confirm button.

By the way, the [learn more link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/release/mobile-app-verification) says

```
Please ensure you wait 24 hours after updating the app-ads.txt before running authentication again.
```

but I confirm successfully in less than 30 minutes.

Comment: Do you know is it ok to delete app Id from  app-ads.txt file after confirming ownership?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.

Comment: How do I get the last value (Certificate Authority ID) ? And should I use DIRECT OR RESELLER if my app is android app with admob ?

Comment: @zivz Maybe this [link](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9363762?hl=en#step2]) helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Just click on confirm ownership button and it will take you to the next step. Even though it seems to be disabled it's still clickable

Comment: I click it but then it again can't confirm it https://imgur.com/a/Wab2fP5